# Postgres how do I update all rows in a table with left join and case?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Assume that I have table A, and table B. Table B contains some rows from table A
How do I run an update like the following?

```
update table A
set A.column = case when B.id is present then B.column else null
from B where B.id = A.id OR B is null
```

**EDIT**

The original query is incomplete, this is the updated one i need help with

```
update table A 
set A.column1 = case when B.id is present then B.column else null end,
 set A.column2 = case when B.id is present then null else A.id end
 from B 
where B.id = A.id OR B is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a subquery:

```
UPDATE A SET A.column = (
    SELECT B.column FROM B WHERE B.id = A.id
)
```

You can use a left join in the `FROM` clause as well to update multiple columns:

```
UPDATE A SET column1 = B.column1, column2 = B.column2
FROM A x LEFT JOIN B ON x.id = B.id 
WHERE A.id = x.id
```

The table A in the `FROM` clause is only to allow a left join with B.

Comment: I have edited the question with a slightly more complex query, would using the subquery approach you've suggested update even the rows that are not present in table B?

Comment: Hi @clemens could you please help?

Comment: Yes, it would. I have extended my answer for updating multiple columns.